# Regex for a specific email for a specific domain

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm looking for a regex to match this: `a_*_*@example.com` where the `*` is any text of any length. Doing this in NodeJS

Additionally I'm looking for a regex that matches any string not including the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a_.*_.*@example\.com` for the first

`^[^@]*$` for the second